# Bash Displaying Syntax Errors When Started

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I accidentally did

```
bash -a
```

While in my terminal. To try to fix it I did

```
set +a
bash -a
bash +a
```

and I removed and install bash-completion but it still returns

```
bash: _parse_usage: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: _parse_usage: line 16: ` -?(\[)+([a-zA-Z0-9?]))'
bash: error importing function definition for `_parse_usage'
bash: _longopt: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: _longopt: line 6: ` --!(no-*)dir*)'
bash: error importing function definition for `_longopt'
```

Whenever I type in bash or try to run a bash script. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's nothing destructive about [`set -a`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin). Does something in your [Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) define `_parse_usage` and `_longopt`?

Comment: I dont think that it destroyed anything because it works fine but it just shows those errors before the things that are returned from the bash file

Comment: AFAIK they're both bash_completion functions - it's almost as if the bash_completion file is being sourced without extglob somehow